# How to draw a symbol on top of another symbol?

Tags: graphics, symbols

I have two circles:

empty circle

```
\circle{5}
```

and solid circle

```
\circle*{3}
```

How can I draw solid one on top of empty one? Can we make a command? I want to put it within the text to show as a symbol. Thanks.

Different things I have copied from internet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\bulletarrow{{\ooalign{\raise0.8ex\hbox{$\bullet$}\cr$\downarrow$}}}
\begin{document}

\raisebox{.5pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt} {8}}}

\circle*{8}

\circle{15}


\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{picture}(60, 40)
\put(20,30){\circle{1}}
\put(20,30){\circle*{5}}
\put(20,30){\circle{8}}
\put(40,30){\circle{1}}
\put(40,30){\circle{2}}
\put(40,30){\circle{3}}
\put(40,30){\circle{4}}
\put(40,30){\circle{5}}
\put(40,30){\circle{6}}
\put(40,30){\circle{7}}
\put(40,30){\circle{8}}
\put(40,30){\circle{9}}
\put(40,30){\circle{10}}
\put(40,30){\circle{11}}
\put(40,30){\circle{12}}
\put(40,30){\circle{13}}
\put(40,30){\circle{14}}
\put(15,10){\circle*{1}}
\put(20,10){\circle*{2}}
\put(25,10){\circle*{3}}
\put(30,10){\circle*{4}}
\put(35,10){\circle*{5}}
\end{picture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What package defines `\circle`? In which context (math, text) are you pretending to use the symbol?

Comment: I am not using any package. "This symbol is represented with \<command>" will be my usage. I guess, it's text version.

Comment: Plus... what have you tried so far? All questions should include the code for a complete small document people can compile to reproduce the issue or understand the context. EDIT: But you say 'I have two circles...'. Where did you get them from if you didn't use a package or define a command? And I don't understand why you want to represent a symbol with another one. Surely that will lead to infinite regress?

Comment: Last one gives me a solid circle within an empty circle but this is an image. Don't know how to use it within text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option using TikZ (adjust the settings to suit your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\mycircle{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-1ex]
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=5pt];  
\fill (0,0) circle [radius=3pt];  
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

A\mycircle B

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Ultra simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\mycircle{\textcircled{\textbullet}}

\begin{document}

This symbol is (for unknown reasons) represented by \mycircle.

The symbol \mycircle{} is (for unknown reasons) not represented by anything.

\end{document}
```

[image: Infinite regress avoided]

Answer (score 5):

This example constructs the symbol with the help of other symbols. They can be used in both math and text mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\obullet}{}
\protected\def\obullet{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \mathbin{%
      \mathpalette\@bullet@o\odot
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\bulletcirc}{}
\protected\def\bulletcirc{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \mathbin{%
      \mathpalette\@bullet@o\bigcirc
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@bullet@o}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$#1#2\m@th$}%
  \hbox to\wd0{\hfil$#1\bullet\m@th$\hfil}%
  \llap{\copy0}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  A \odot B \obullet C \bulletcirc D
\]
\begin{center}
  text \obullet\ text \bulletcirc\ text
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Also a symbol can be constructed via environment `picture`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\bulletcircle}{}
\protected\def\bulletcircle{%
  \begingroup
    \settoheight{\unitlength}{A}%
    \begin{picture}(1,1)%
      \put(.5,.5){\circle{1}}%
      \put(.5,.5){\circle*{.65}}%
    \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  abc \bulletcircle\ text
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

Tailor made for a `\stackinset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\mycirc{\kern3.5pt\raisebox{3pt}{\stackinset{l}{}{c}{}{\circle{5}}{\circle*{3}}}}
\begin{document}
E\mycirc B
\end{document}
```

[image]